# Gitlab shows different commit author than git config --global user.name

Tags: git, gitlab, global, commit, author

I know I can edit my username in gitlab but I don't want to.

I assumed that after running this:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Full name"
```

every commit will be signed by "Your Full name" but when I push commits my username from gitlab shows up instead.

When I run above command locally ( `git config user.name "Your Full name"` ) then "Your Full name" shows up as an author. I don't want to run this command in every repo before pushing so I am wondering how to make gitlab show username from my global config as a commit author

Comment: Did you run `git config --global user.name "Your Full name"` before or after you made your commits? What does `git config user.name` say? (No "Your Full name" because that is setting it in your local .git/config.)

Comment: before, `git log` shows user.name from my global config as an author. It has the same value as `git config --global`

Comment: With the same email address as you use on Gitlab? I suspect it is a Gitlab feature that it will match your email address to a Gitlab account and use the account's info. Try changing your name on Gitlab.

Comment: I have the same email address in `git config`, `git config --global`, gitlab and ssh pub key. I know I can change my name on gitlab but I don't want to, I am confused why `user.name` from global config doesn't work but if I change config locally, in repo, it works

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about how the commit is displayed on Gitlab.com? Gitlab decides how it wants to display the commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Gitlab decides how it displays the commits, and they have decided to use the name on the Gitlab account matching the email address. For example, [this commit on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/NebulousLabs/Sia/-/tree/ba2fde875ea43e976036e7c55a004aa113b91614) is authored by "Peter-Jan Brone" but in the Git commit the name is "PJ".

I assume they do this to provide a consistent display of who committed what. The user.name on a commit may change. It would be confusing to show some commits as by "M Schwern", "Michael Schwern", "Michael G Schwern", "Schwern" and "MS" if they're all coming from the same account. By using the name on the matching Gitlab account, the commits can be displayed consistently.

Using the same example above, the same email address commits to that repository as both "PJ" and "Peter-Jan Brone".

To change what is displayed on Gitlab, you'll have to change your Gitlab profile.

Comment: You are right, I have just tested it. If user.email from git config is matching email from gitlab profile then username from gitlab is used if it doesn't then user.name from git config is used.